# Nonlinear optimization of constraint parameter - subdifferential?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, subgradient

**Disclaimer:** I discovered that the FAQ suggests to post research-level to [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129312/quadratic-optimization-with-parameter-in-constraint) instead of math.stackexchange. I "moved" the question accordingly, cp. [post at mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129312/quadratic-optimization-with-parameter-in-constraint). Sorry for the confusion!

**Question:** Given a function $q: \mathbb R^{N\times N}\mapsto \mathbb R$,

$$
q(\Omega) = \inf_{\vec r}\,\,\vec r^T\vec r - \vec w^T\vec r\quad\quad \text{s.t.}\quad\quad (\Omega + \lambda I)\vec r = \vec w\quad\quad \text{and}\quad\quad \vec r > 0.
$$

where $\Omega\in\mathbb R^{N\times N}, \vec r, \vec w\in\mathbb R^{N}$ and $I\in R^{N\times N}$ is the identity matrix. What is the "gradient" $\partial q$ that minimizes $q(\Omega)$?

**First attempt:** My current hope is to minimize $q$ using subgradient calculus. In a slightly related problem, the function

$$
q(\lambda) = \inf_x \left(f(x) + \lambda g(x)\right)
$$

can be shown to be minimized by the subgradient $\partial q = g(x)$ (and convergence can be proofed). However, in my problem the argument of $q$ is in the constraint. For parameters in the constraint an approach like multi-parametric quadratic constrained optimization might go in the right direction. However, they rely on branch-and-cut algorithms whereas I want a distributed gradient approach.

Thanks!